# How to avoid automatic data type conversions in SQLite

Tags: implicit-conversion, sqldatatypes, rsqlite

I am creating a table in RSQLite and would like to avoid errors that may come from misspecification of data types. I tried to add a check(typeof()) constraint. However, SQLite appears to be doing an automatic conversion from numeric to text despite the check constraint. I also tried to create a "STRICT" table but the problem persists. Can anyone help me to figure out what's going on and avoid the automatic conversion? Many thanks!

The code below adds a check constraint to the ID variable specified as a type "text" in the "TEST" table. However, when a numeric value is inserted, instead of a text value, no error is flagged. When querying the data, it appears that the numeric value has been automatically converted into a character value.

> dbExecute(conn = dbconn, "CREATE TABLE TEST(

- ID TEXT CHECK(TYPEOF(ID) = 'text'))")
  [1] 0

> data <- data.frame(ID = 1)
> str(data)
> 'data.frame':   1 obs. of  1 variable:
> $ ID: num 1
> dbWriteTable(conn = dbconn, "TEST", data, append = T)
>
> out <- dbSendQuery(conn = dbconn, statement = "select * from TEST")
> fetch(out)
> ID
> 1 1.0
> str(fetch(out))
> 'data.frame':   0 obs. of  1 variable:
> $ ID: chr